# Twitter Bootstrap modal windows shade not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have Page with modal windows which I open with this JS code:

```
 $('.open-modal').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var object = $(this);
    modals(object.attr('href'))
})
function modals(href) {
    $("#Modal").modal("hide");
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'html',
        //data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.modal-body').html(data);
            $("#Modal").modal('show');
            $('.ChangeToEdit').on('click', function (event) {
                $("#Modal").modal('hide');
                event.preventDefault();
                var object = $(this);
                modals(object.attr('href'))
            })
        }
    });
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and example of buttons:

```
<a class="open-modal" href="/User/Edit/14">Edit</a> |
<a class="open-modal" href="/User/Details/14">Details</a> |
<a class="open-modal" href="/User/Delete/14">Delete</a>
```

If User open modal with Details he will find modal with details and button to edit this data. After pressing that button modal window should close and open new one  with edit.
Unfortunately. When user use edit button on details modal a second " shade" appears and stay there even after edit modal is closed.

What I'm doing wrong? why second shade shade from first modal doesn't disappear?

Comment: Is it possible that the getting with ajax includes a bootstrap script tag? I guess including bootstrap more than once could result in similar problems.

Comment: Instead of `@Html.ActionLink...` you could provide rendered HTML.

Comment: @dfsq I updated my question with samples of buttons. Robert It isn't Bootstrap is included only in the layout. Other pages have no script tags with bootstrap. More this error only appears when I try go from Details modal to Edit modal. When I click Edit everything works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try to do`$(".modal-backdrop").removeClass();` after you closed the first modal.